# "I used" or I've used"?

Tags: grammaticality

Which is the correct way of saying the following sentence (if there is a "right" way)

- I used different symbols to make it great.
- I've used deifferent symbols to make it great.

Comment: I used to be used to using different symbols to make it great, but you never get used to used symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context somewhat.

> I used different symbols to make it great.

I just finished the project and it has different symbols on it

> I've used different symbols to make it great.

In the past I have done this kind of project and made it great by using symbols.

In the latter case you probably could reword the second half of the sentence to make it clearer.